# Rollback edit privilege missing from help center

Tags: bug, edits, privileges, help-center, rollbacks

Reading a quite recent question raised [on MSO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280720/1190388), I immediately went on to read the help center entry on [full edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

There is actually no mention of attaining the rollback privilege at all.

A little digging later, I found that this exists on an entirely [separate section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) about editing in general.

Why is the rollback not covered in the privileges section?

Comment: Well, rollback is an edit, kind of a shortcut. However it's really not trivial, agree it better be clarified in the help center.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are there any recent attempts on adding the "Rollback" explanation into the privileges section? I just was misguided myself on why I couldn't do it for a certain question and came here to find out the reason.

Comment: @Montag451 no, none that I know of at least. (I don't work for SE)